# How to get the type of what in the string in python

Tags: python, string, casting, integer

I wrote a function that gets an argument, that should be a string, Now the function should know what is the data type of what in the string; Let's Say an example: -

```
def input_type(value):
   pass

print(input_type("1"))
```

now the function should return the type is an integer

I need this with **string** type and **float** type and **integer** type.

Comment: Well, you can `try` to parse it as a `float` and if that fails `try` as `int` and if that fails, assume it’s a string…

Comment: Use isinstance initially to ensure that *value* is a string then try int() first then float(). You have to attempt the conversion in this order because int('10.5') will fail whereas float('10') will succeed. Doing it the other way round can produce ambiguous results

Answer (score 1):

For this specific question one could do this:-

```
def input_type(value):
  if isinstance(value, str):
    try:
       int(value)
       return 'int'
    except ValueError:
      pass
    try:
      float(value)
      return 'float'
    except ValueError:
      pass
    return 'string'

print(input_type('1'))
print(input_type('1.5'))
print(input_type('abc'))
print(input_type(999))
```

This will output:-

int
float
string
None

Comment: The problem was when i do float() function on like "2" it returns to me float but it returns int

Comment: "2" is ambiguous. It could be either int or float. However, "2.5" can only be float but not int. That's why you have to test for int before float. If you pass "2" to my code it will return "int"